# Python 'destructor' to kill children process in module

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm developing a MyModule that reads some (huge and realtime) data from c library and writes it to PyTables. Due to amount of data needed to be collected (even 300MB/s) PyTables are accessed on separated Process and packets are pushed through multiprocessing Queue.

```
class Tape(object):

    def __init___(self):
        self.writeq = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.killq = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.recorder = MyRecorder(self.writeq, self.killq)
        self.recorder.start()

    def Record(self, recording):
        if isinstance(recording, numpy.ndarray):
            self.writeq.put(recording)

    def Close(self):
        self.killq.put("time to go")
        self.recorder.join()
        for q in (self.writeq, self.killq):
            q._buffer.clear()
            q.close()
            q.join_thread()

class MyRecorder(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, writeq, killq):
        self.writeq = writeq
        self.killq = killq
        self.handle = tables.openFile("/tmp/recoding.h5")
        self.number = 0
        super(MyRecorder, self).__init__()

    def run():
        running = True
        while running:
            record = None
            command = None
            try:
                record = self.writeq.get(block = False)
                if isinstance(record, numpy.ndarray):
                    a = self.handle.createArray("/", "record%08d" % self.number, recording)
                    a._f_close(True)
                    self.number += 1
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

            try:
                command = self.killq.get(block = False)
                if isinstance(command, basestring) and command == "time to go":
                    running = False
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

            if record is None and command is None:
                time.sleep(0.001)

        self.handle.flush()
        self.handle.close()
```

The users would use my module this way:

```
tape = MyModule.Tape()
device = MyOtherModule.Device()
while True:
    record = device.get_latest_data_as_numpy_array()
    if record is not None:
        tape.Record(record)
    else:
        break

tape.Close()
exit(0)
```

**Problem**

I want to make sure that if user forgets to call `tape.Close()` the process inside tape is still terminated when the exit is called (or program terminates other way). The `tape.Close()` call has to be called one way or another.

1. Adding `__del__` call to Tape class doesn't work as it is never called. Also I'd like to avoid using `with tape:` context syntax (there might be multiple tapes created and used at the same time).
2. I have added watchdog threads to do the heartbeat between Tape and Myrecorder - but it is only useful if any of those crash and are teared by exceptions.
3. The `device.get_latest_data_as_numpy_array()` call can take several seconds to return, so adding a timer to MyRecorder, to check if there was no data in x seconds is not really a solution.

Comment: Use a context manager and "force" the users to use `with MyModule.Tape() as tape:`

Comment: http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/

Comment: You can also take a look at the atexit module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

Comment: @Torxed - Thanks, but I have mentioned that context manager is not what will work for me.

Comment: @Maciek  - atexit will only work for static functions... I would have to maintain a global list of references to the Tape objects inside module. Nasty but may work.